# rollback transaction when mapping exception to responses with Jersey ExceptionMapper

Tags: exception, transactions, jersey

I'm using a custom Jersey ExceptionMapper to map my unchecked exceptions into error responses (as described in the [documentation](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/representations.html#d0e6352)). My problem is that the transaction is not rolled back, every DB modification made before the exception is persisted.

The same thing happens if, instead of using the ExceptionMapper, I throw a WebApplicationException.

How can I send an error response to the client preserving the normal behavior (rollback the transaction)?
I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18427512/spring-transactional-dont-rollback-when-exception-is-mapped-by-exceptionmapper), but I don't use spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is use a [`RequestEventListener`](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/monitoring_tracing.html#d0e16007) to manage the transaction throughout the lifetime of the request. You can listen for [`RequestEvent.Type`s](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/2.28/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/monitoring/RequestEvent.Type.html), which includes events such as `RESOURCE_METHOD_START`, `ON_EXCEPTION`, `RESOURCE_METHOD_FINISH`, etc. You can begin the transaction at the beginning of the request processing and commit or rollback the transaction depending on if it a successful processing or an exception is thrown.

This is pretty much what [Dropwizard](https://www.dropwizard.io/1.3.9/docs/) does with it's `@UnitOfWork`. You can see how it is all implemented in [this package](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/tree/release/1.3.x/dropwizard-hibernate/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/hibernate). Look at the [`UnitOfWorkApplicationEventListener`](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/release/1.3.x/dropwizard-hibernate/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/hibernate/UnitOfWorkApplicationListener.java). You'll see how they implement what I was talking about above.

Comment: HI Paul, thanks for the hint! I also found a possible solution in keycloak source code [here](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/services/error/KeycloakErrorHandler.java).. just in case someone else encounters the same problem.